# Ничего не выполняется после polling

Tags: python, telegram, heroku

Делаю бота telegram, он работает на heroku. Так как раз в день он перезагружается, то боту нужно делать автозапуск.

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
main()
```

проблема в том, что метод main не выполняется. Но мне нужно чтобы бот запускался сам и он мог реагировать на мои команды.

```
if __name__ == "__main__": Heroku
    main()

while True:
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=5)
```

Такое тоже не работает, бот не отвечает на команды..
Подскажите пожалуйста, чем можно заменить polling или другое решение данного вопроса

Answer (score 0):

несколько дней мучался, а ответ оказался прост..
threading.Thread(target=FUNCTION).start() на каждую функцию